# label.text for table cell returns nil (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view with static content and I'm trying to access label text of selected row, but it returns nil for some reason. What might cause it?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as UITableViewCell?
    let label = currentCell!.textLabel
    if label != nil {
        let text = label!.text
        NSLog(text ?? "Label text is nil")
    } else {
        NSLog("Label is nil")
    }
}
```

In my example I see Label text is nil

Comment: If the tableview has static content, why do you need to access the label text? Can't you just access the data in the array that is filling out your tableview? Something like `let text = labelTextArray[indexPath.row]`

Comment: @KaylaGalway because there is no data for that table - it's static from IB. . Elena, are you sure that you're accessing the right label? Maybe your text is in some other label, like 'detailTextLabel' or some other you've added manually?

Comment: @jovanjovanovic, the issue was in cell's style (it was custom) and after I changed it I got the text

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the cell's style over the attribute inspector to be anything other than "custom". 
If it is a custom one, from your code, it looks like you're not targeting it.

Comment: Solved the issue! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (link),

You should not be storing model data in your cell's views. A cell is a view object. It's for displaying information and collecting input from the user.

You should be storing your data in a model object. For table views, an array (or an array of arrays for a sectioned table view) is a good choice.

Instead of trying to fetch text from a cell label, use the indexPath to look up the string you need from your model.